# Carry forward annotation from interface to generated java class when using Immutables

Tags: java, immutables-library

I am using Immutables (http://immutables.org) in my Java interface to generate builders and immutable object. I have created a custom method level annotation called @Primary (denoting which attribute is primary field) that I have used to annotate one of my methods in the Immutable interface. I don't see the annotation in the generated java class created by immutables. I tried looking at BYOA (Bring Your Own Annotation) but that does not help.

Is there a way to get the @Primary annotation onto the generated immutable java class?

**UPDATE  (Based on Sean's suggestion below)**

I now have a below config based on

**package-info.java**

```
package com.mypackage;


import com.mercuria.recon.custom.annotation.Primary;
import org.immutables.value.Value;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.PACKAGE, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS) // Make it class retention for incremental   compilation
@Value.Style(passAnnotations=Primary.class)
public @interface MyStyle {}
```

**Primary Annotation**

```
package com.mypackage.custom.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Primary {

}
```

I am seeing an error in package-info.json where in it says MyStyle should be declared in its own file. I am not sure the above config is correct. Please can you advise where I am going wrong?

Comment: package-info.json? The file is supposed to be called package-info.java. And you should not define a custom annotation there, but instead annotate the package (see my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure which annotations to pass with the `@Style` annotation, which you can use on package level.

E.g. create a file called package-info.java in any package and annotate it with

```
@Style(passAnnotations=Primary.class)
```

See: [Style customization](http://immutables.github.io/style.html) (explains about where to store a `@Style` annotation, but doesn't mention the `passAnnotations` mechanism)

Here's an example package-info.java file:

```
@Style(passAnnotations = YourAnnotation.class)
package com.yourapp;

import com.yourapp.annotations.YourAnnotation;
import org.immutables.value.Value.Style;
```

note that the annotations are above the `package` declaration, and the `import`s below.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for pointing me to Styles. I am not sure I have understood it completely.  I have updated my initial post with how I have configured. Please can you let me know where I might be going wrong.

Comment: The Styles annotation configures your code generation. You can annotate your class directly with it, or if you want to apply the same settings to multiple classes, annotate the package.

Comment: I believe I am not setting up the package-info.java file correctly. What should be the contents of this file. Can you please let me know what is incorrect in the sample I pasted above?

Comment: Thanks Sean, works now. Sorry, package-info.json was a typo .