# Can I specify annotations to be added to Immutable generated classes?

Tags: java, immutables-library

I have some code using Immutables (https://immutables.github.io/) which generates a `ImmutableEntity` class with a method like:

```
public static ImmutableEntity of(EntityId id,
                                  Locale language,
                                  String text)) {
  return validate(new EntityMeldung(id, language, text));
}
```

but to work with MongoDB POJOs I need that method to have annotations like:

```
@BsonCreator
public static ImmutableEntity of(@BsonProperty("id") EntityId id,
                                  @BsonProperty("language") Locale language,
                                  @BsonProperty("text") String text)) {
  return validate(new ImmutableEntity(id, language, text));
}
```

The `Entity` interface only defines some getters and I'd rather continue to let Immutables generate the `ImmutableEntity` class and methods like `of()`

Should I be looking at [Annotation Injection](https://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#annotation-injection)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Carry forward annotation from interface to generated java class when using Immutables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631472/carry-forward-annotation-from-interface-to-generated-java-class-when-using-immut)

Comment: @Rcordoval similar question but not a duplicate since this `of` method doesn't exist in `Entity` - it's generated by Immutables